# Validación en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una duda, ¿Cómo valido en MVC? Es decir, tengo un `Index` y en este se ingresa un valor numérico con un mínimo de 4 caracteres y un máximo de 6 caracteres. Pero, no entiendo como se valida al momento de decirle que si ese valor numérico no existe en la `Base de Datos` me muestre un error tipo `PopUp` y se quede en el `Index` y que en caso contrario se muestre la siguiente vista con datos.

**Clase Cuotas:**

```
public class Cuotas
    {
        [Display(Name ="Titulo")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Este campo es requerido.")]
        [StringLength(6, ErrorMessage = "Longitud entre 4 y 6 caracteres.", MinimumLength = 4)] 
        public double Titulo { get; set; }
}
```

**Clase ConexiónSQL:**

```
public List<Cuotas> cargarDatos(double? tit)
    {
        List<Cuotas> salida = new List<Cuotas>();
        string con = "cadena";
        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(con)) {
            conexion.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT titulo, apellido +', '+nombre,Cuota, vencimiento FROM V_CuetaWeb  WHERE titulo = @tit ORDER BY cuota DESC";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tit", tit);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                double titulo = Convert.ToDouble(dr.GetDouble(0));
                string nombre = dr.GetString(1);
                double cuota = Convert.ToDouble(dr["cuota"].ToString());
                DateTime? venc = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["vencimiento"].ToString());

                Cuotas p = new Cuotas(titulo, nombre, cuota, venc);
                salida.Add(p);
            }
            conexion.Close();
            return salida;
        }            
    }
```

**Controlador:**

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Cuotas cuotas) {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("ChAzul");
            }
            else {
                return View("Index");
            }
        }

        public ActionResult ChAzul(string titulo) {
            ConexionSQL cn = new ConexionSQL();
            return View(cn.cargarDatos(Convert.ToDouble(titulo)));
        }
```

**Index:**

```
<center>
    <div style="width: 350px">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 form-horizontal">
                <br />
                @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Titulo)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Titulo, new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = "autofocus" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Titulo, null, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <br />

                <input type="submit" value="Buscar"/>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</center>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

**Web.Config:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
```

**Global.asax:**

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = true;
            HtmlHelper.UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled = true;
        }
```

He hecho esto pero no he dado con el resultado, puesto que al ingresar un valor sea de 1 caracter me lleva hacia la otra vista...

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo leas detenidamente este artículo [Validación de formularios en ASP.NET MVC - Unobtrusive Validate](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2018/11/12/validaci%C3%B3n-de-formularios-en-aspnet-mvc-unobtrusive-validate)

Comment: Hola,gracias por responder, actualizaré el código porque seguí tu ejemplo pero no ha dado resultado. @RafaelAcosta

Comment: creo que deberías usar ajax para hacer la query de si existe o no y sino existe el dato que buscar mostrar el popup o lo que sea.

Comment: He actualizado el código, si puedes decirme donde está el error te lo agradecería @RafaelAcosta

Comment: No se usar ajax @hawks

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo: En cuanto pueda lo miro.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias @RafaelAcosta

Comment: He revisado los errores, pero me he topado con que el problema está en que el tipo de valor ingresado (en este caso título, es double) y por ello no me reconoce el `[StringLenght(6, etc)]` ya que al comentar esa línea me redirigió hacia los datos cuando ingreso un valor correcto pero no me valida la cantidad de caracteres. ¿Alguna forma de solucionarlo? @RafaelAcosta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validé la caja de texto de la siguiente manera (Para el control de caracteres máximo):

```
<input type="number" id="titulo" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" name="titulo" maxlength="6" placeholder="Ingrese su título..." required="required">
```

Y para las demás validaciones, lo hice desde el controlador:

```
public ActionResult ChAzul(double? titulo) {
    ConexionSQL cn = new ConexionSQL();
    var suscriptor = cn.cargarDatos(Convert.ToDouble(titulo));
    var caracteres = Convert.ToString(titulo).Length;
    if (caracteres <= 3 || caracteres > 6)
    {
        ViewData["Mensaje"] = "La cantidad de caracteres no puede ser menor a 4 (cuatro) ni mayor a 6 (seis).";
        return View("Index");
    }
    if (suscriptor.Count <= 0)
    {
        ViewData["Mensaje"] = "Lo sentimos, este título no existe.";
        return View("Index");
    }

    if ((caracteres >= 4 && caracteres <= 6) && suscriptor.Count > 0) {
        return View("ChAzul", suscriptor);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```